# Cannot debug web projects anymore "invalid pointer"

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

I haven't been working on web projects for a while but last time I did debugging was working just fine.

I have worked on some console apps recently where debugging is working fine. I now went back to a SharePoint 2010 project, set a break point and hit F5 but first got this prompt:

[image: Attaching IntelliTrace Debug Engine debugger to process failed]

I click OK and next prompt is

[image: Cannot debug some of the code in process w3wp.exe]

I also tried to attach to process (w3wp.exe) instead of F5 but no difference

I tried to disable IntelliTrace but then got
[image]

I tried to repair .Net 4.5.1 in the control panel
I tried to repair VS2012 in the control panel
I tried to create a new project but same error

Since debugging is working fine for console apps I guess it's something with IIS/web.config but not sure if it has changed since last time I looked at this project.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you encounter these errors, there are several things to consider. Below is a troubleshooting about this issue, please first go to ‘Things to Check’ section, then consider the remaining items based on your hardware and software configuration: [Error: Unable to Start Debugging on the Web Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwesw3ee%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Diagnosing 'The debugger is not properly installed'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2004/04/16/114828.aspx)